# TableView Cell changes when scrolling up

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I understand the cell is being reused so there is a problem with my if statement when the cell is being presented again. But I don't understand why the if statement causes the cell to change when scrolling up.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ExploreTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExploreTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell
    let rowIndex = self.dataArray.count - (indexPath.row + 1)
    let newsRowObj = self.dataArray[rowIndex] as NewsHeadline
    cell.newsTitle.text = newsRowObj.source

    if (newsRowObj.source == "reddit") {
        cell.newsTitle.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    return cell
}
```

When `source == "reddit"` the text is set to red. But when I scroll back up, the cells are randomly red.

Comment: I think the answers given are all valid, but I prefer to use `prepreForReuse()`. In there you can tell the cell how it originally should look like.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are reusing some "reddit" cells without handling the case that the new cell isn't. You need to add an `else` handling where you set the `textColor` back to the original color.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ExploreTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExploreTableViewCell
// Configure the cell
   let rowIndex = self.dataArray.count - (indexPath.row + 1)
   let newsRowObj = self.dataArray[rowIndex] as NewsHeadline
   cell.newsTitle.text = newsRowObj.source

   if (newsRowObj.source == "reddit") {
       cell.newsTitle.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
   }
   else{
       cell.newsTitle.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
   }
   return cell
}
```